# 肥満度を表す体格指数を計算するプログラムを作成したが、計算結果が正しい値にならない

Tags: c

身長、体重を入力することで、身長、体重、BMI、肥満度、適正体重を出力するプログラムを作成したいのですが、コンパイルはできるものの、明らかにおかしい数字が出てきてしまい、どこがおかしいのかがよくわかりません。
とりあえず自分は以下のようにプログラムをしました。

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void print_nw(double height,double weight)
{
     double bmi,tekisei;
     
     bmi=weight/(height*height);
     tekisei=height*height*22;
     printf("身長=%.1f cm,体重=%.1f kg\n",height,weight);
     printf("BMI=%.1f\n",bmi);
     printf("適正体重は%.1f kgです。\n",tekisei);
     if(bmi<18.5){
       printf("低体重です。\n");
     } else if(18.5<=bmi && bmi<25){
       printf("標準体重です。\n");
     } else if(25<=bmi && bmi<30){
       printf("肥満一度です。\n");
     } else if(30<=bmi && bmi<35){
       printf("肥満二度です。\n");
     } else if(35<=bmi && bmi<40){
       printf("肥満三度です。\n");
     } else {
       printf("肥満四度です。\n");
     }
}

int main()
{
    double h,w;
    printf("身長(cm)? ");
    scanf("%lf",&h);
    printf("体重(kg)? ");
    scanf("%lf",&w);
    
    print_nw(h,w);

    return 0;
}
```

＜実行結果＞

```
$ ./a.out
身長(cm)? 163
体重(kg)? 45
身長=163.0 cm,体重=45.0 kg
BMI=0.0
適正体重は584518.0 kgです.
低体重です。
```

しかし、正しくプログラムができていれば、以下のような結果が出てくるはずです。

```
身長(cm)? 163
体重(kg)?　45
身長=163.0 cm,体重=45.0 kg
BMI=16.9
適正体重は58.4 kgです。
低体重です
```

どの部分を直せばいいのでしょうか。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BMI計算で掛ける身長は単位がmだった気がするので、単純に`height*height`の計算が`163×163(cm)`ではなく`1.63×1.63(m)`の計算になる必要があるような気がします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。void関数のbmi,tekiseiのheightの部分をともに、height/100とプログラムを入力したら、コンパイル時にきちんとした答えが出てきました。